# C# Entity Framework sorting and paging giving unexpected results

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

When I am using Entity Framework with `OrderBy` and `Skip` and `Take`, there are duplicate records and some records are not displaying.

This is the code:

```
jobs = context.Jobs.Include("Company").
                OrderBy(x => x.Company.Name).
                Skip((page - 1) * PageSize).
                Take(PageSize).ToList();
```

However if I order by some `Job` property like `x => x.Title`, there aren't any issues. Issue is only when sorting with some related entity of job. In my code `Job` and `Company` have one-to-many relationship.

Please help with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query doesn't completely define the order of resulting rows.

Say we have a table:

```
Id Name
1  Bar
2  Foo
3  Bar
```

When ordering by `Name`, the following result sets will be possible:

```
Id Name
1  Bar
3  Bar
2  Foo
```

and

```
Id Name
3  Bar
1  Bar
2  Foo
```

Each call may return any of this sets, so if we have page size `1` it is possible to get strange result like this:

```
Id Name
1  Bar // 1st set
1  Bar // 2nd set
2  Foo // 1st set
```

Adding some unique attribute (PK in most cases) to your key will fix this behavior.

Given key `Name, Id` there's only one possible result:

```
Id Name
1  Bar
3  Bar
2  Foo
```

So your query should look like this (assuming `JobId` is PK):

```
jobs = context.Jobs.Include("Company").
            OrderBy(x => x.Company.Name).
            ThenBy(x => x.JobId).
            Skip((page - 1) * PageSize).
            Take(PageSize).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. It fixed the issue. But why results were alright when ordered by Title but wrong when ordered by some related entity of Job like Company.Name ?